# How to transform dictionary output of flatten json into list of records

Tags: json, python-3.x, flatten

I have tried extensively following various posts to come up with a generic function to flatten JSON data coming out of an API to load into a relational database.  While my function seemed to work in some cases in others due to varying degrees of nesting it would not.

I have found the python **flatten_json** module actually does fully flatten out a dictionary recursively regardless of the varying levels, however it outputs a varying number of dictionary keys / or columns, where as I want a fixed set up of columns and multiple rows.

I am trying to find a way to convert the output of flatten_json into a list of dictionaries with fixed number of keys.

For example if I have the json (just a single record sample:

```
data = {'recs': [{'Type': 'ACCREC',
 'InvoiceID': 'e3d96555-2876-4364-a46a-7551a4f52611',
 'Reference': '',
 'Payments': [{'PaymentID': 'f41fd62d-48d2-4bab-975b-c770d1541014',
   'Date': '/Date(1622073600000+0000)/',
   'Amount': 1485.0,
   'Reference': '',
   'HasAccount': False,
   'HasValidationErrors': False}],
 'CreditNotes': [],
 'AmountDue': 0.0,
 'AmountPaid': 1485.0,
 'AmountCredited': 0.0,
 'DateString': '2021-05-14T00:00:00',
 'DueDateString': '2021-05-27T00:00:00',
 'Status': 'PAID',
 'LineAmountTypes': 'Exclusive',
 'LineItems': [{'ItemCode': 'Train-MS',
   'Description': 'Half day training - Microsoft Office - for your Priority Services Team (Session 3)',
   'UnitAmount': 450.0,
   'TaxType': 'OUTPUT',
   'TaxAmount': 45.0,
   'LineAmount': 450.0,
   'AccountCode': '200',
   'Item': {'ItemID': '32147268-0576-46db-9c3b-adfd311035f5',
    'Name': 'Half day training - Microsoft Office',
    'Code': 'Train-MS'},
   'Tracking': [{'Name': 'Region',
     'Option': 'South',
     'TrackingCategoryID': '093af706-c2aa-4d97-a4ce-2d205a017eac',
     'Options': []}],
   'Quantity': 1.0,
   'LineItemID': 'b45d3c74-028e-48b5-9f87-109960488e5b'},
  {'ItemCode': 'Train-MS',
   'Description': 'Half day training - Microsoft Office - for your Lending Service Analysts (Session 2)',
   'UnitAmount': 450.0,
   'TaxType': 'OUTPUT',
   'TaxAmount': 45.0,
   'LineAmount': 450.0,
   'AccountCode': '200',
   'Item': {'ItemID': '32147268-0576-46db-9c3b-adfd311035f5',
    'Name': 'Half day training - Microsoft Office',
    'Code': 'Train-MS'},
   'Tracking': [{'Name': 'Region',
     'Option': 'South',
     'TrackingCategoryID': '093af706-c2aa-4d97-a4ce-2d205a017eac',
     'Options': []}],
   'Quantity': 1.0,
   'LineItemID': '61537ea1-d09f-4afc-84a1-2c1c7a32eb4c'},
  {'ItemCode': 'Train-MS',
   'Description': 'Half day training - Microsoft Office - for your Customer Support Team (Session 1)',
   'UnitAmount': 450.0,
   'TaxType': 'OUTPUT',
   'TaxAmount': 45.0,
   'LineAmount': 450.0,
   'AccountCode': '200',
   'Item': {'ItemID': '32147268-0576-46db-9c3b-adfd311035f5',
    'Name': 'Half day training - Microsoft Office',
    'Code': 'Train-MS'},
   'Tracking': [{'Name': 'Region',
     'Option': 'South',
     'TrackingCategoryID': '093af706-c2aa-4d97-a4ce-2d205a017eac',
     'Options': []}],
   'Quantity': 1.0,
   'LineItemID': '71eda5c8-16eb-4204-af26-e0fe95dc5e65'}],
 'SubTotal': 1350.0,
 'TotalTax': 135.0,
 'Total': 1485.0,}]
```

flatten_json returns:

```
{'recs_0_Type': 'ACCREC',
 'recs_0_InvoiceID': 'e3d96555-2876-4364-a46a-7551a4f52611',
 'recs_0_Reference': '',
 'recs_0_Payments_0_PaymentID': 'f41fd62d-48d2-4bab-975b-c770d1541014',
 'recs_0_Payments_0_Date': '/Date(1622073600000+0000)/',
 'recs_0_Payments_0_Amount': 1485.0,
 'recs_0_Payments_0_Reference': '',
 'recs_0_Payments_0_HasAccount': False,
 'recs_0_Payments_0_HasValidationErrors': False,
 'recs_0_CreditNotes': [],
 'recs_0_AmountDue': 0.0,
 'recs_0_AmountPaid': 1485.0,
 'recs_0_AmountCredited': 0.0,
 'recs_0_DateString': '2021-05-14T00:00:00',
 'recs_0_DueDateString': '2021-05-27T00:00:00',
 'recs_0_Status': 'PAID',
 'recs_0_LineAmountTypes': 'Exclusive',
 'recs_0_LineItems_0_ItemCode': 'Train-MS',
 'recs_0_LineItems_0_Description': 'Half day training - Microsoft Office - for your Priority Services Team (Session 3)',
 'recs_0_LineItems_0_UnitAmount': 450.0,
 'recs_0_LineItems_0_TaxType': 'OUTPUT',
 'recs_0_LineItems_0_TaxAmount': 45.0,
 'recs_0_LineItems_0_LineAmount': 450.0,
 'recs_0_LineItems_0_AccountCode': '200',
 'recs_0_LineItems_0_Item_ItemID': '32147268-0576-46db-9c3b-adfd311035f5',
 'recs_0_LineItems_0_Item_Name': 'Half day training - Microsoft Office',
 'recs_0_LineItems_0_Item_Code': 'Train-MS',
 'recs_0_LineItems_0_Tracking_0_Name': 'Region',
 'recs_0_LineItems_0_Tracking_0_Option': 'South',
 'recs_0_LineItems_0_Tracking_0_TrackingCategoryID': '093af706-c2aa-4d97-a4ce-2d205a017eac',
 'recs_0_LineItems_0_Tracking_0_Options': [],
 'recs_0_LineItems_0_Quantity': 1.0,
 'recs_0_LineItems_0_LineItemID': 'b45d3c74-028e-48b5-9f87-109960488e5b',
 'recs_0_LineItems_1_ItemCode': 'Train-MS',
 'recs_0_LineItems_1_Description': 'Half day training - Microsoft Office - for your Lending Service Analysts (Session 2)',
 'recs_0_LineItems_1_UnitAmount': 450.0,
 'recs_0_LineItems_1_TaxType': 'OUTPUT',
 'recs_0_LineItems_1_TaxAmount': 45.0,
 'recs_0_LineItems_1_LineAmount': 450.0,
 'recs_0_LineItems_1_AccountCode': '200',
 'recs_0_LineItems_1_Item_ItemID': '32147268-0576-46db-9c3b-adfd311035f5',
 'recs_0_LineItems_1_Item_Name': 'Half day training - Microsoft Office',
 'recs_0_LineItems_1_Item_Code': 'Train-MS',
 'recs_0_LineItems_1_Tracking_0_Name': 'Region',
 'recs_0_LineItems_1_Tracking_0_Option': 'South',
 'recs_0_LineItems_1_Tracking_0_TrackingCategoryID': '093af706-c2aa-4d97-a4ce-2d205a017eac',
 'recs_0_LineItems_1_Tracking_0_Options': [],
 'recs_0_LineItems_1_Quantity': 1.0,
 'recs_0_LineItems_1_LineItemID': '61537ea1-d09f-4afc-84a1-2c1c7a32eb4c',
 'recs_0_LineItems_2_ItemCode': 'Train-MS',
 'recs_0_LineItems_2_Description': 'Half day training - Microsoft Office - for your Customer Support Team (Session 1)',
 'recs_0_LineItems_2_UnitAmount': 450.0,
 'recs_0_LineItems_2_TaxType': 'OUTPUT',
 'recs_0_LineItems_2_TaxAmount': 45.0,
 'recs_0_LineItems_2_LineAmount': 450.0,
 'recs_0_LineItems_2_AccountCode': '200',
 'recs_0_LineItems_2_Item_ItemID': '32147268-0576-46db-9c3b-adfd311035f5',
 'recs_0_LineItems_2_Item_Name': 'Half day training - Microsoft Office',
 'recs_0_LineItems_2_Item_Code': 'Train-MS',
 'recs_0_LineItems_2_Tracking_0_Name': 'Region',
 'recs_0_LineItems_2_Tracking_0_Option': 'South',
 'recs_0_LineItems_2_Tracking_0_TrackingCategoryID': '093af706-c2aa-4d97-a4ce-2d205a017eac',
 'recs_0_LineItems_2_Tracking_0_Options': [],
 'recs_0_LineItems_2_Quantity': 1.0,
 'recs_0_LineItems_2_LineItemID': '71eda5c8-16eb-4204-af26-e0fe95dc5e65',
 'recs_0_SubTotal': 1350.0,
 'recs_0_TotalTax': 135.0,
 'recs_0_Total': 1485.0}
```

I need the output to be split into a list of dictionaries something along the lines of :

```
[{'recs':0, 'Type':'ACCREC', 'InvoiceID':'e3d96555-2876-4364-a46a-7551a4f52611',
..
'Payments':0,'f41fd62d-48d2-4bab-975b-c770d1541014',
..
'LineItems ':0,'LineItemID':'b45d3c74-028e-48b5-9f87-109960488e5b'},
{'recs':0, 'Type':'ACCREC', 'InvoiceID':'e3d96555-2876-4364-a46a-7551a4f52611',
..
'Payments':0,'f41fd62d-48d2-4bab-975b-c770d1541014',
..
'LineItems ':1,'LineItemID':'61537ea1-d09f-4afc-84a1-2c1c7a32eb4c'}]
```

Ie each number in the key effectively results in break out of a new element / record in list

Somehow iterate through the key names and split out the dictionary into a list.

I have tried to get the keys along the lines of:

```
for k,v in data.items(s):
    cols = k.split('_')
```

But i have not been able to work out a way to dynamically process where there are different levels per record.

Can someone provide some guidance on how I might go about this?

Comment: In the _something along the lines of_ after `'Payments':0,` you have values without a key.